# background of activity_splash.xml not changing

Tags: android, xml

i was coding a splach screen in android. I coded a bg_gradient.xml and added to activity_splash.xml using android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient" but not showing any changes to activity_splash.xml.
this is My activity_splash.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width = "match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my bg_gradient.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:endColor="#9b2a58"
    android:startColor="#00032a"
    android:angle="90"></gradient>
</shape>
```

Comment: can you add your java code too? and if you add a solid color to bg did it change?

Comment: xml code in both files is pretty clear and no issues with it. Please share your activity code. It can help us debug this

Comment: ACTUALLY I didn't code any activity till now. I was coding layout of My app as i shared the file named as activity_Splash.xml . i want to add gradient background in splash screen.

Comment: This error is only showing in android studio . As i pasted the same code in intellij idea then there working fine. I am unable to recognise the issue in android studio